# Convert Asp.net core Page Modal object to Vue,js data object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asp.net-core

I am trying to mix Asp.netcore Razor Pages and Vue.js in a Project where  The page modal returned will contain the data and the Vue controller will use that data to do the Clientside rendering and other UI interactions

Pagemodal.cs

```
   public class SampleQuestionModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<QuestionViewModal> questionViewModals = new List<QuestionViewModal>();
        public void OnGet()
        {
            MYEXAMAPI.Controllers.QuestionApiController questionApiController = new MYEXAMAPI.Controllers.QuestionApiController();

            questionViewModals = questionApiController.GetQuestion();
        }
    }
```

This is my Razor where I uses the page modal to show data

```
@page
@model MYEXAM.SampleQuestionModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SampleQuestion";
}

<h1>SampleQuestion</h1>
<script src="~/js/vue.js"></script>

<ul id="app">
    <li v-for="item in questionViewModals">
        {{ item.fullQuestions }}
    </li>
</ul>

<script>

    var vueApp = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            questionViewModals: @Json.Serialize(Model.questionViewModals) //This is not working 
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What did you mean by `This is not working` ? Did you use the Chrome DevTools to check if there is error in js or the result of `@Json.Serialize(Model.questionViewModals)` ? What's your actual result of the rendered page ?

Comment: yes it was not working and @hardik answer solved the issue. but not sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about ASP.net -- but try to move `@Json.Serialize(Model.questionViewModals)` this piece of code to `created` hook.

```
<script>

var vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    created() {
        this.questionViewModals = @Json.Serialize(Model.questionViewModals);
    },
    data: {
        questionViewModals: null
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working code , you could refer to :

```
@page
@model RazorPages3_0Test.SampleQuestionModel

<h1>SampleQuestion</h1>

<ul id="app">
  <li v-for="item in questionViewModals">
    {{ item.fullQuestions }}
  </li>
</ul>

@section Scripts
{
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script>
    var vueApp = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        questionViewModals: @Json.Serialize(Model.questionViewModals) 
      }
   })
  </script>
 }
```

*Result*

[image]

You could download Vue.js from [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html)